# How to embed dll from "class project" into my project in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll

I have a standard "class library" project with a set of classes that I use to import in almost all my new projects.

The way I work is creating a new Solution with an empty project, which is my main project, and then I add to the solution the mentioned class library project, this way I can see both projects in the Soluction Explorer and even see the library code or update it if needed. Then I write the code in my main project and I compile.

This lead me to have 2 files when I compile: file `*.exe` and `stdlib.dll`

Some cases I use the lib for very small tools that I want to redistribute in a easy and clean why, so I would like to embed the `stdlib.dll` generated from my class library project into my `*.exe` file.

I'm pretty sure there must be a why to do this in my Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express but I don't know how.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891550/embedding-dlls-inside-of-a-wpf-application-with-pictures-visual-basic
it works same with vb.net

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a more 'step-by-step' version of [Alex's procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025506/117870) to embedding the assembly.

1. Add the desired assembly (stdlib.dll) to the project's resources.
   Go to the **Resources** tab of the Project Properties and choose *Add Resource > Add Existing File...*
2. Switch to the **Application** tab and click on the **View Application Events** button.
3. Add this code to the *ApplicationEvents.vb* code that opens.

   ```
   Private Sub AppStart(ByVal sender As Object, 
     ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
       AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf ResolveAssemblies
   End Sub

   Private Function ResolveAssemblies(sender As Object, e As System.ResolveEventArgs) As Reflection.Assembly
       Dim desiredAssembly = New Reflection.AssemblyName(e.Name)

       If desiredAssembly.Name = "the name of your assembly" Then
           Return Reflection.Assembly.Load(My.Resources.STDLIB) 'replace with your assembly's resource name
       Else
           Return Nothing
       End If
   End Function
   ```
4. Now compile your project and you'll have the dependent assembly incorporated into the output as a single file.

Note that sometimes you may have the dependent assembly in the output folder. This is because VS is preconfigured to copy all dependent assemblies to the output path. You can override this by going to the **References** tab of the project's properties and then set the **Copy Local** property of the dependent assembly to *False*. This will stop the assembly from being copied to the output directory.

Comment: Potentially stupid question: why doesn't selecting Embedded Resource in the Build Option do this for you? Put another way: why is any code required?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: The only reason I can think of is... *Because this is how it works.* Consider this... the .NET framework does a lot of work loading assemblies if you leave them as DLL files in the EXE path or some other standard path. If you however decide to Embedded Resource it, the framework has no way of knowing whether the resource is an assembly you want to load at run time or it is something you want to work with in any other way. It therefore relies on you to tell it where the desired assembly is and hence the need to write all this code.

Comment: **A small note for those wondering:** Replace `"the name of your assembly"` with the exact name of the Assembly, as you would type in code. If the name is `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack`, then the value of the string will be `"Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack"`.

Comment: @AlexEssilfie Hmm. I wish Microsoft implemented a simpler solution in VS itself, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can embedd your `Assembly` (.dll in your case) into your project by selecting "Add existing file" and then change the Build Option to "Embedded Ressource".

You then add a `Handler` for the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` event which gets fired as soon as you first access the library inside your code.

That handler code looks like this: (Notice the fully qualified assembly path inclusive correct namespacs. I'd wrap it in a function which gets called on startup of your application.

```
   AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve,
            Function(sender As Object, args As System.ResolveEventArgs) As System.Reflection.Assembly
                Dim ressourceName = "YourNamespace.YourSubNamespace." + New AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll"
                Using stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(ressourceName)
                    Dim assemblyData(CInt(stream.Length)) As Byte
                    stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length)
                    Return Assembly.Load(assemblyData)
                End Using
            End Function
```

You can then deploy your tool without any additional files.

Comment: It looks more "trickier" than I thought, but thanks anyway. I'll give it a try.