# How to embed several DLL files into project in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-assembly

I visited this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025127/how-to-embed-dll-from-class-project-into-my-project-in-vb-net), and I want to load multiple files. How can I do that?

The problem is that this return only allows one assembly (I don't know how to return more that  one assembly), so, If I want to load more than one?

Answer (score 0):

That event handler will be called for any assembly resolve request that cannot be fulfilled by the system, so it will be invoked multiple times. As such the fact that it can return only 1 assembly is not a problem, just make sure you return the one that is requested. Make a table or use a `select ... case` statement.