# Embedding and Deploying ressources into VB project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I got a problem with some ressources. I got a simple .exe file, that is accessed by my application. So I saved the exe tool within my project folder and everything was simple. But now I want the exe to be embedded inside my application, to keep everything nice and clean.
I want my app to be a single file executable, that will deploy its dependencies and stuff on its own.

So read a little tutorial on stack: [How to embed dll from "class project" into my project in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025127/how-to-embed-dll-from-class-project-into-my-project-in-vb-net)

I got the .exe into my ressources and pasted the code into my ApplicationEvents.vb (don't kill me for CP ;) ). Next I tried to execute the whole thing, but nothing happend. By executing the application step by step (F8), I saw, that the AddHandler call is executed, but the Deploy Function gets never called.

Next I read a tutorial at MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I tried to change the persitence mode of my ressource as described, but the Persistance option is disabled.

So what can I do to deploy my second .exe?

Comment: You say that it's an EXE so why would following instructions for a DLL work?  How EXACTLY are you interacting with this EXE?

Comment: All you need to do is add the .exe to your project, select it in the explorer and in the properties: Copy to Output Directory select copy if newer...

Comment: I am interacting with the .exe by simply calling it with different parameters. So I want to deploy it, call it and delete it again, just to keep my application portable and simple.
I don't want to copy the exe to my output directory. I can do this by hand, but I want a single app, that deploys the exe on need.